# SQL loop through an array and run a query multiple times

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an array with some status ids

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I want to run this query

```
SELECT firstname, lastname FROM calls
WHERE status_id = "STATUS ID"
ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 50
```

What would the syntax be to do a loop though the `status_id` array and run the query each time?

I want to end up with 250 rows with each group of 50 having a one of the `status_id`'s.

Comment: Do you want all of them at once or separate result sets?  Also, which RDBMS are you using.  I doubt it's both mysql and postgresql.

Comment: Hey, in postgres please i've adjusted the query btw missed a bit off

Comment: status_id = "STATUS ID"?  In the first part of the question, status_id appears to be an integer.  And why order by RANDOM()?  If you don't need them in order, just take them as they come.

Comment: Yeah it is an integer just doing that to represent thats where the status id is

Comment: i added this bit to the query

ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 50 

And this bit

What i want to end up with is 250 rows with each group of 50 having a one of the status id's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't be terribly efficient, but it's the best I can think of:

```
select firstname, lastname
FROM (
  SELECT firstname, 
         lastname, 
         row_number() over (partition by status_id order by random()) as rn
  FROM calls 
  WHERE status_id = ANY (ARRAY [1,2,3,4,5])
) t
where rn <= 50;
```

The inner select will retrieve all rows with the desired values for `status_id` and will give each row a random row number for each value in `status_id`. The outer select will then only select 50 rows for each status (unless there are less than 50 for that specific status of course)

Comment: `ORDER  BY status_id`

Answer (score 1):

Use In operator:

```
 SELECT firstname, lastname FROM calls WHERE status_id IN [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: I've adjusted the question how would you do it now?

Comment: I think you need round brackets.